# Handling Result.Canceled in OnActivityResult

Tags: android, xamarin, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

I want to create a function which asks for turning on bluetooth till user does it.
I have the code which asks user to enable the bluetooth:

```
 var enableBluetooth = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ActionRequestEnable);
                    StartActivityForResult(enableBluetooth,1);
```

And I want to see the results using OnActivityResult:

```
protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, [GeneratedEnum] Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (requestCode  == 1)
            {
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Ok");
                }
                else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Canceled");
                }
                else Console.WriteLine("Other Error");
            }else Console.WriteLine("Wrong request code");
        }
```

And if I click Ok i can see in output window Ok, but when I press cancel any of comments are not being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refering android developper :

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result
and bluetoothChat :https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

Try this as an Activity result :

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else 
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NOK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

On Xamarin following chatexample : 
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothChat

onActivityResult should looklike this :

```
public override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
     switch (requestCode)
     {
          case 1:
              if (Result.Ok == resultCode)
              {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "OK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              else
              {
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "NOK",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              break;
       }
}
```

Comment: Ok I added in OnActivityResult:` const int RESULT_OK = -1;
             const int RESULT_CANCELED = 0;` and changed if statements:` ((int)resultCode == RESULT_OK) and (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED)` but still i got the same problem.

Comment: Add a log in your code then that print the result variable after the condition on requestcode. Maybe it doesn't event pass the block

Comment: I tried to print the result anywhere in OnActivityResult but when I click cancel nothing had been shown.

Comment: Now I don't get any results. Could you take a look at the code? [link]https://github.com/KCPR13/LFapp/blob/master/LFapp/MainActivity.cs#L60[/link]

Comment: I am not a xamarin user but your code seems different from XAmarin bluetoothChat example : https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChatFragment.cs

Try implementing the public method onActivityResult with your conditions on the requestcode and resultcode.
Also replace Toast with console.write